# Add buttons to the new TinyMCE WP Editor. Javascript API

Tags: tinymce, editor, dropdown, buttons

I've added more buttons to a TinyMCE instance using the new Javascript API available since WordPress version 4.8.

As you can see in the following code block, I could add more buttons but I'm not able to add the headings/paragraph/pre dropdown menu. How do I add it?

```
wp.editor.initialize( 'editor-id', {
    mediaButtons: true,
    tinymce:      {
        toolbar1: 'bold,italic,bullist,numlist,link,blockquote,alignleft,aligncenter,alignright,strikethrough,hr,forecolor,pastetext,removeformat,codeformat,undo,redo'
    },
    quicktags:    true,
} );
```

---

**Short.**

**I have this:**

[image]

**I want to add this menu:**

[image]

Comment: try with `formatselect`

Comment: @mmm , Excellent. That;s it. Please create an answer on this page, so I can mark it as resolved and you'll earn the reputation.